# How can I fix the figure shift in enumerate?

Tags: graphics, floats, enumerate

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3]
\begin{enumerate}
\item One
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=.4]{example-image-a}
\captionof{figure}{Image In Enumerate}
\end{center}
\item Two
\end{enumerate}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=.4]{example-image-a}
\captionof{figure}{Image Out Enumerate}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

And output;

[image]

We see the Figure 2 layout. But in the enumerate Figure 1 is shifted to the left. Even the caption is slipped. How can I show Figure 1 like Figure 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be instead of using `\begin{center}...\end{center}`, you could better use `figure` environment with `\centering` option, as in:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3]
\begin{enumerate}
\item One
\begin{figure}[h!]\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.4]{example-image-a}
\captionof{figure}{Image In Enumerate}
\end{figure}
\item Two
\end{enumerate}
\begin{figure}[h!]\centering
\includegraphics[scale=.4]{example-image-a}
\captionof{figure}{Image Out Enumerate}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

thereby, getting

[image]

Now as you can see, both images are within `enumerate` environment with their captions aligned.

Comment: and the user of course risks that the images floats away despite the `!h`

Comment: @daleif I dont understand, what you mean by that.

Comment: A figure floats, if say the second figure is close to a page break, the float will not be placed here, it will move to the next page, and some text from the next page may be moved to this page to fill in the gap. Remember 'h' does not mean here, neither does '!h', it means "here if possible", and a part of the definition of a 'h' floats, is that there has to be text below it, so it cannot come as the last thing on a page.

Answer (score 2):

Here I use `enumitem` to set the `leftmargin` to 0pt which gets the figures centered relative to the original margins, but with `itemindent` set to  15pt, so that the `\item` header is set properly.

I left the `\end{enumerate}` before the 2nd figure (as did the OP) only to demonstrate that things were centered properly.  For proper approach, the `\end{enumerate}` should follow the 2nd figure.  In this case, it will not cause any horizontal changes.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twocolumn,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-3]
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=0pt,itemindent=15pt]
\item One
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=.4]{example-image-a}
\captionof{figure}{Image In Enumerate}
\end{center}
\item Two
\end{enumerate}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=.4]{example-image-a}
\captionof{figure}{Image Out Enumerate}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You are as fast as ever.